# Run only part of a Staggered Animation

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-animation

I'm working through the [staggered animations tutorial](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/animations/staggered-animations) and really like the way you can compose an animation out of multiple tweens by attaching them all to the 
same animationcontroller:

```
AnimationController animationController;
Animation<double> opacity;
Animation<double> width;
Animation<double> height;

opacity = Tween<double>(
      begin: 0.0,
      end: 1.0,
    ).animate(animationController1), //attach to animationController

width = Tween<double>(
      begin: 0.0,
      end: 1.0,
    ).animate(animationController1), //attach to animationController

height = Tween<double>(
      begin: 0.0,
      end: 1.0,
    ).animate(animationController1), //attach to animationController
```

My question is:
Using this setup and assuming the animations overlap is it possible to run only part of the animation, i.e. only one of the tweens? Suppose I ONLY want to animate the opacity and not all three {opacity, width and height}. At the same time I want to have the flexibility to run all three. How would I do that?

Comment: One way is you can use different controllers for different animations.

Comment: Yes, but how do I use different controllers for the _same_ animation?

Comment: Need not. Why different controllers for same animation???? Let me see if I can turn up with an example for you.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have the same problem